# Tornado RDBMS integration

Tags: python, tornado, rdbms, blocking, nonblocking

Typically the RDBMS drivers are blocking, while Tornado is a non-blocking server. This leads to irrational use of async, when performing CRUD operations, because the IOLoop will be blocked until that SQL query finishes.

I am working on a project that uses RDBMS as a DB (because of ACID), but which also requires Websockets to orchestrate some fancy functionlaity (i.e. push notifications) and after some googling I am thinking of using Tornado, because both usual REST and Websockets can be implemented in one app.

Browsing the web I found this snippet (here: https://gist.github.com/methane/2185380):

```
import time

from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor   # `pip install futures` for python2

MAX_WORKERS = 4


class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)

    @run_on_executor
    def background_task(self, i):
        """ This will be executed in `executor` pool. """
        time.sleep(10)
        return i

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self, idx):
        """ Request that asynchronously calls background task. """
        res = yield self.background_task(idx)
        self.write(res)
```

What it basically does is pushes the CRUD task to a separate thread.
My question is: is this the default approach of dealing with blocking RDBMS drivers when using an async HTTP server? Are there any other ways of minimizing these blocking bottlenecks? Is it even reasonable to use a blocking RDBMS driver with an async server?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of dealing with an RDBMS in Tornado.

There are some libraries for various DB's for doing them async in Tornado.
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links

You can also use GEvent to get asyncronous db access in Tornado.

Another option is to use a Python3 async io library with Tornado such as:
https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

As you noted another option is to offload the DB workload elsewhere. You could use a Message Queue like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ, multiple threads, multiple processes, To an API on another box.

You can also use standard blocking database access mechanisms, they will still work in Tornado, they just block until they return, this may or may not be a problem.

I gave a talk about Momoko, Aiopg, and GEvent at PyOhio last year:
http://pyvideo.org/video/3698/from-synchronous-to-asynchronous-postgres-with-to

Comment: Thanks! I've read that all Python async RDBMS drivers/ORMs are not that reliable. People are saying 'It's hard to create an ORM, It's even harder to do it right'. Also, what about concurency when using async DB access?

Comment: What's the purpose for using asyncio + Tornado? They both have IOLoops, why not just use default Tornado one? Even for non web stuff Tornado's loop can be successfully used in the same maner.

Comment: 1. As far as the reliability, I haven't had any issues yet, but that's not to say that there aren't issues. There are a lot less people using the async stuff than the synchronous stuff so with less eyes, I would expect more issues.
2. I agree that ORMs are hard. I hate ORMs based on ActiveRecord implementations. Since I only use Postgres I created a one file orm that only does Object and relationship mapping and none of the other stuff.
3. Concurrency can be an issue in async, At least in postgres when you turn on async you can't use and automatic txn stuff, you have to call begin and commit

Comment: Why would you use asyncio and Tornado? Tornado is an asynchronous web framework written before asyncio existed thus why it supplies its own IOLoop. You would want to use asyncio with Tornado when you want to use a library that was written for asyncio in your Tornado web app. You may also not want Tornado as a dependency on your non-web stuff.

Comment: Using asyncio for some lib support makes sense, in fact we might actually need it later in the project. What is wrong with ActiveRecord? Maybe I haven't worked with it that much, but it feels alright from my experience. For the project we are working one, however, I think it would be best to use a non async ORM, because transactional stuff is mission critical and async raises questions with concurency. So I think that offloading SQL tasks to other threads might be the right choice for us.

Comment: Active Record based ORMs such as Django's and SQLObject really break down when you are writing complex queries. If all you need is basic CRUD, then it doesn't matter as much. SQLAlchemy can handle just about anything you throw at it, but it is big and has a steep learning curve. Personally when I talk to a database I want to write SQL and not use some crazy abstraction created by the ORM maintainer, which is what I hate about most ORMs. A lot of it personal opinion, but with ORMs trying to get what you want out of the DB using an ORM is often very tricky.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to carefully think about how you design 'your' ORM, because hardcoding SQL inside the app raises security concerns. With a well designed ORM the devs have already thought about input sanitization, passign params independantly from the query, etc. For now, our queries are going to be mostly CRUD, but when we get to statistical analisys, these are gonna get pretty complex quickly. Also, using an ORM saves time when working with mulitple DB engines, you typically don't need to rewrite all your queries if you decide to change the DB. p.s. SQL is a horrible language. I hate it =)

Comment: As far as security concerns, database drivers typically handle the input sanitization stuff for you (psycopg2 does). If multiple DB engines are a requirement for your project than I agree that something like SQLAlchemy is better. Most people don't need multiple DB engines and the advantage of dealing with only one DB is that you can take advantage of many great features that each DB has for instance in Postgres you can use (JSONB, Postgis, Range Types, lateral joins). SQL seems to be a love it or hate it thing, Personally I love it because it is meant to do one job and it does it very well.